# pySpark MinMaxScaler restore with different originalMin and originalMax

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pipeline with multiple states, one of the stages is a MinMaxScaler. Something like:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, MinMaxScaler

stages = [
   ...
   VectorAssembler(inputCols=["value"], outputCol="value_vec", min=0.0, max=1.0),
   MinMaxScaler(inputCol="value_vec", outputCol="value_scaled")
   ...
]

data = spark.createDataFrame([(0, 0), (1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)], ["id", "value"])

pipeline_model = Pipeline(stages=stages).fit(data)
pipeline_model.save(path)
```

Applying the pipeline gives the following correct result:

```
scaled = pipeline_model.transform(data)
scaled.show()

+---+-----+---------+--------------------+
| id|value|value_vec|        value_scaled|
+---+-----+---------+--------------------+
|  0|    0|    [0.0]|               [0.0]|
|  1|   10|   [10.0]|[0.3333333333333333]|
|  2|   20|   [20.0]|[0.6666666666666666]|
|  3|   30|   [30.0]|               [1.0]|
+---+-----+---------+--------------------+
```

However, if I later on restore the pipeline and use it on a different dataframe (different than the one used to fit the pipeline):

```
pipeline_model = PipelineModel.load(path)
data2          = spark.createDataFrame([(4, 0), (5, 5), (6, 10), (7, 40)], ["id", "value"])

scaled = pipeline_model.transform(data2)
scaled.show()

+---+-----+---------+--------------------+
| id|value|value_vec|        value_scaled|
+---+-----+---------+--------------------+
|  4|    0|    [0.0]|               [0.0]|
|  5|    5|    [5.0]|[0.16666666666666...|
|  6|   10|   [10.0]|[0.3333333333333333]|
|  7|   40|   [40.0]|[1.3333333333333333]|
+---+-----+---------+--------------------+
```

How can the scaled value for record with `id = 7` be greather than 1 if the max value specified in the MinMaxScaler is 1?

Comment: your pipeline_model is fitted with `data`, not with `data2`. You need to refit the pipeline using `data2`.

Comment: That's exactly the thing, I want to be able to use my stored pipeline model on different data and still have the scaling to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: if you're going to fit it again to a different data, you can save the pipeline rather than the pipeline model.

Comment: I don't need to fit it again, I just want to MinMaxScaler to scale between 0 and 1

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but if you are going to supply the transformer with new data, you must ensure that new data is within the range of the original data. In your case, the offending value is the `40` which is greater than the original maximum (`30`). That's why you get a value greater than 1. To avoid this in the future, add or create a dataframe with a row with the maximum value you expect for `inputCols`. If you don't know it beforehand, you'll need to fit it in every time